# How does &pointer have type pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pointer-to-pointer

```
struct node
{
       int a;
};

int main()
{
 
    struct node y = {23};
    struct node *x = &y;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is some code i came across, i messed around with the code and found out that **"&x"** has type **pointer to pointer**. I am very confused on how this could be so i drew it out and made a program to try and find out how below, x has address 0x123 and y has address 0x24:

[image]

**My understanding is `&x` returns the address of the pointer x, `*&x` returns the address that `x` points too, **IT RETURNS A ADDRESS NOT ANOTHER POINTER**. So how is the type a pointer to pointer? As far as i can see:**

1. x is a pointer
2. de-referencing x is the same as *x which is of type (struct node *)
3. I think it is the same because x is just an alias for the pointer variable, there is no difference when referring to its address or alias (x).

Lastly here is my program that illustrates this and further confuses me because what i thought is correct in the program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
       int a;
};


int main()
{
    struct node y = {23};
    struct node *x = &y;

    printf("\n\nstruct node y = {23}\nstruct node *x = &y;\n\n");

    printf("address of x is: %p\naddress of y is: %p\n", &x, &y);

    printf("\n&x address is:   %p\n", &x);
    printf("*&x address is:  %p\n", *&x);
            
}
```

The output of this program looks like this:

```
struct node y = {23}
struct node *x = &y;

address of x is: 0x7ffdedcc2da0
address of y is: 0x7ffdedcc2d9c

&x address is:   0x7ffdedcc2da0
*&x address is:  0x7ffdedcc2d9c
```

What i though was correct and comparing it to my diagram shows it is correct.

Comment: _pointer-to-pointer_ maybe such as `**p` is not important point at this problem. The important thing is that `node *x` can be thought such as `DWORD x` and it contains just a DWORD value(address of `y`). So, `&x` is the address of variable `x` and `*&x` is the value pointing at DWORD value `x` containing :)

Comment: `*x` has type `struct node`, not type `struct node *`.  Each time you apply the `&` operator, you add a level of indirection.  Each time you apply the `*` operator, you remove a level of indirection (in code, not in declarators).

Comment: p.s. `&x` is address of `x`, and `*&x` is the value of x (`==x`). the value of `x` is the address of `y`, so `*&x` is equals with `&y`.

Comment: "My understanding is &x returns the address of the pointer x, `*&x` returns the address that x points too, IT RETURNS A ADDRESS NOT ANOTHER POINTER." *This is where your misconception is*. "Address" is **not a type**. The word "address" means "number that tells you where something is in memory". The word "pointer" means either "variable that stores an address", or "value that represents an address".

Comment: `*&x` is just `*(&x)`, i.e., the thing that `&x` points at, i.e., `x`. The `*` *dereferencing operator* that appears in *expressions* is *completely different* from the `*` used in *type declarations* to indicate pointer types. (Just as how they're both different from `*` meaning multiplication.)

Comment: I misread you the first time. `&x` has type  pointer-to-pointer because `x` is a pointer, and `&` gives you the address of something, i.e., a pointer to it.

Comment: I tried to write an answer, but all of this is better addressed by a tutorial or FAQ such as http://c-faq.com/ (try sections 4 and 6 in particular), or by asking on an actual *discussion forum* such as Reddit or Quora. Stack Overflow is not really the right place to address misconceptions and issues with understanding the fundamentals of the language you are using.

Answer (score 4):

> My understanding is &x returns the address of the pointer x, *&x returns the address that x points too, IT RETURNS A ADDRESS NOT ANOTHER POINTER. So how is the type a pointer to pointer? As far as i can see:

Let's walk through this step by step and make sure we are being precise about all the terminology.

`x` is of type `struct node *`, i.e., a pointer-to-node. It is, therefore, a pointer.

`&x` is an *expression* (in the same way that `1 + 2` is an expression). Expressions do not "return" anything; they *evaluate to* some result which has a *value* and a *type*. In this case, we apply the `&` operator to `x`. The resulting value has a *type* of pointer-to-pointer-to-node (in C syntax, `struct node**`). You don't need to do any difficult thinking to understand this: the type that results from `&` is pointer-to-(whatever was the type of the thing that `&` is applied to). In our case, the (whatever was the type of the thing that `&` is applied to) is "pointer-to-node", and we directly substitute that in: `typeof(&x)` is `(typeof x)*` which is `(struct node *)*` which is `struct node **`. (I don't think you can actually use `(typeof x)*` as a type declaration; I'm just showing the type calculus here in something that looks vaguely C-ish.)

The *value* of that expression is the address of the existing `x` variable. That's *what `&` does*. The issue here is that "a address not another pointer" makes no sense, because "address" *isn't a different kind of type*. When we say "the address of x", we mean "a thing which has a type that is pointer-to-(whatever is the type of x), and a value which tells us where x is located in memory".

When we write `*&x`, that is another expression, in which we apply the `*` operator to the subexpression `&x`. Functionally, `*` undoes the effect of `&`; it means "the thing at the specified location", and the type has one level of "pointer-to" *removed*.

> de-referencing x is the same as *x which is of type (struct node *)

Careful with your language. `*x` indeed "is the same as dereferencing x", which is to say, it *is the way that we express* that idea in code. `x` is a pointer of type `struct node *`; thus, `*x` is the pointed-at value, of type `struct node`.

```
printf("\n&x address is:   %p\n", &x);
printf("*&x address is:  %p\n", *&x);
```

I think this is where you confused yourself. The thing that you labelled as `"&x address"` is not the address of `&x`, but instead `&x` itself, i.e. the address of `x`. (Just like how in the first `printf` you printed the very same thing - `&x` - and labelled it "address of x".) Of course printing `*&x` gives you the same thing as printing `&y`, because `*&x` is just `x` (the `*` undoes the `&`), which is `&y` (because that's how `x` was initialized). You can do this kind of reasoning without even needing to think about the types (although you *will* need to think about types in the long run, in order to write correct code).

---

There are, of course, limitations: you cannot just write pairs of `&` and `*` together as much as you want and have them cancel out. `*` needs to be applied to something that is a pointer, and using `&` later can't save you from that requirement. Similarly, `&` needs to be applied to something that has a defined location, and using `*` later can't save you from that requirement. In particular, you can't apply consecutive `&&` to something, because the address produced by the first `&` is temporary and doesn't conceptually have an address (in the compiled code, it might for example only ever appear in a register and never be written to memory).

Comment: thank you for this answer it has helped me a lot since you mentioned the idea of expressions which i was not very familiar with before. So i have laid out my understanding and have came to this conclusion could you tell me if i am correct please? So ```&x``` is a pointer to pointer because:  Firstly the expression ```&x``` is a pointer to the address of ```x```, upon further evaluation of the result (which is the address of x), the address of x behaves like a pointer like object to the address of y (&y). Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: " Firstly the expression &x is a pointer to the address of x" No; you're still misusing the terminology. `&x` is a pointer *to x*; also, `&x` *is equal to* the address of x. Those two statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

The unary `&` operator gives a pointer to its operand. `&thing` is a pointer to `thing`.

If `x` is a pointer to a `struct node`, then `&x` is a pointer to a pointer to a `struct node`.

> My understanding is `&x` returns the address of the pointer `x`, `*&x` returns the address that `x` points [to]…

No, `*&x` gives `x`.

Unary `*` is the opposite of unary `&`. `*&thing` is `thing`.

Whatever `thing` is, `&thing` is a pointer to `thing`. And, given a pointer, such as `&thing`, `*` gives whatever the pointer points to. Since `&thing` points to `thing`, `*&thing` is `thing`.

Comment: ah ok so the expression ```&x``` is a pointer itself? because the actual expression ```&x``` is technically a object that holds a memory address?

Comment: `&x` *evaluates to* a memory address, the address of `x`. That makes it a pointer. However, it is not "an object" in any relevant sense. I assume you don't mean "instance of a class" (C doesn't have those), but it also isn't an *lvalue*. You can't *assign to* `&x` because it doesn't, itself, have a defined memory address. It's just the result of a calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if a variable `n` has type `foo`, then the address of that variable, i.e. `&n` has type `foo *` i.e. a pointer to `foo`.

All variables have an address, including pointer variables.  So if `m` has type `foo *` i.e. pointer to `foo`, then `&m` has type `foo **` i.e.  pointer to pointer to `foo`.

In your example, `x` has type `struct node *`.  It contains `&y` i.e. the address of `y`.  And since `y` has type `struct node` its address has type `struct node *`.  If you were to print `x` you would see that it has the same value as `&y`.

Also, when the indirection operator `*` is applied to the result of the address-of operator `&` they cancel each other out.  So the expression `*&x` is exactly equivalent to the expression `x`.

Addressing your specific points:

> x is a pointer

Correct, as it is declared with a pointer type

> de-referencing x is the same as *x which is of type (struct node *)

Dereferencing `x` is exactly `*x`, however since `x` already has type `struct node *` that means that `*x` has type `struct node`.

> I think it is the same because x is just an alias for the pointer variable, there is no difference when referring to its address or alias (x).

`x` *is* a pointer variable which contains the address of `y`, meaning that the value of `x` is equal to the value of `&y`.

Comment: So i have laid out my understanding and have came to this conclusion could you tell me if i am correct please? So &x is a pointer to pointer because: Firstly the expression &x is a pointer to the address of x, upon further evaluation of the result (which is the address of x), the address of x behaves like a pointer like object to the address of y (&y). Is this a correct assumption?