# In C can expressions be pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memory-address, pointer-to-pointer

```
struct node
{
       int a;
};


int main()
{
    struct node y = {24};
    struct node *x = &y;
 
    return 0;
}
```

I have recently been having trouble to see how the expression `&x` is a pointer to pointer type (struct **node) but after doing a little research i found out that since a pointer is just **a object that holds (or points to) a memory address**,then the expression `&x` is technically a pointer since it yields a address (**with the actual expression `&x` the pointer that can be used in code**).

`&x` is technically of type pointer to pointer because `&x` is a pointer to the address of `x`, the yielding of the address of x gives us another pointer aka the actual pointer x, hence it being pointer to pointer.

My question is, in C how can expressions be used as a pointer? Am i correct to assume that `&x` can be used in code as a pointer, after all it is just an expression, in memory how does it look? Maybe i am overthinking and the matter is as simple as `&` returning a pointer to its operand. **Lastly is my understanding correct of how it is a pointer to pointer?**

Comment: `&x` works because `x` refers to an item *in memory.*  That is, x is generally a *declared variable.* The same is not necessarily true of expressions like `(a + b)`.

Comment: `&x` is not of type *pointer to pointer*; it is simply the memory address of `x`.  The `&` operator literally means "Address Of."

Comment: `the matter is as simple as & returning a pointer to its operand` -- It is indeed that simple.

Comment: so what is the type of "&x" because everyone here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869317/how-does-pointer-have-type-pointer-to-pointer says so

Comment: I didn't read that whole post, but I don't see anywhere where anyone is asserting that the type of `&x` is a pointer to a pointer to whatever  type `x` is.  If x is an `int`, the type of `&x` is pointer to an int, or `int*`.

Comment: Eric's answer says "If x is a pointer to a struct node, then &x is a pointer to a pointer to a struct node."

Comment: That's right.  If `x` is already of type `int*`, then `&x` would be a pointer to a pointer, or `int**`.

Comment: So is it correct to assume that the actual expression ```&x``` is a pointer in this case

Comment: It is correct to assume that in *any* case.  `&x` is a pointer to whatever type `x` is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In the OP's code, `x` is a pointer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey are you saying ```&x``` is a pointer because ```&x``` is a object that points to a memory address hence making it a pointer?

Comment: I think you may be overthinking this.  If x is an `int`, `&x` is simply an operator that converts `int` to `int*`.

Comment: @programmerc3981143 `&x` is a pointer by the definition of the address-of operator.

Comment: what is this definition @dbush

Comment: @programmerc3981143: Look [here](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/), under the subheading "Address Of Operator."

Comment: @programmerc3981143 From the C standard section 6.5.3.2p3: *The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’,
the  result  has  type  ‘‘pointer  to type’’.*

Comment: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`  Why didn't you just consult the standard in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this Draft C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ##### 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators
>
> …
> **Semantics**
> 3    The unary **`&`** operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type “*type*”, the result has type “pointer to *type*”. …